# java.util.logging include jSessionId in each log entry

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java.util.logging

I am using j2se logger in my application.
Is there any way to log jSessionId with each log entry in the log file without modifying the current log statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this. This can be done with ThreadLocal, a servlet filter and a log filter. The steps are given below:

Create a session id holder class with ThreadLocal variable:

```
public abstract class SessionUtil {
      private static final ThreadLocal<String> sessionIdThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
      public static String getSessionId() {
            return sessionIdThreadLocal.get();
      }
      public static void setSessionId(String jSessionId) {
            sessionIdThreadLocal.set(jSessionId);
      }
      public static void removeSessionId() {
            sessionIdThreadLocal.remove();
      }
}
```

Create a ServletFilter and inside the init() method of the ServletFilter class, attach the log filter with the log handlers:

```
Handler[] handlers = Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();
for (Handler handler : handlers) {
LogFilter logFilter = new MyLogFilter();
handler.setFilter(logFilter);
}
```

Inside the doFilter() method of the ServletFilter class, add the below line to add JSessionId to ThreadLocal:

```
SessionUtil.setSessionId(request.getSession(false).getId());
```

Inside the finally block of doFilter() method in ServletFilter class, add the below line to remove the JSessionId from ThreadLocal after the request is processed:

```
SessionUtil.removeSessionId();
```

Define the log filter class:

```
public class MyLogFilter implements LogFilter {
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
    if (SessionUtil.getSessionId() != null && 
            !SessionUtil.getSessionId().toString().equals("")) {
        StringBuilder sessId = new StringBuilder(SessionUtil.getSessionId().toString());
        String methodName = record.getSourceMethodName();
            if (methodName != null && !methodName.equals("")) {
            if (!methodName.endsWith(sessId.toString())) {
                    record.setSourceMethodName(sessId.insert(0, " ").insert(0, methodName).toString());
            }
            } else {
            record.setSourceMethodName(sessId.toString());
            }
    }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now the sample log entries will be like:

```
[4/12/13 10:00:46:685 EDT] 00000020 SampleClass    I com.example.SampleClass sampleMethod() [ROatVgqdnLd-ls3_ONvXcXU] Sample message
```